# Upgrading from windows 7 starter to ultimate

Tags: windows-7

Will upgrading from Windows 7 basic to ultimate result in deletion of all data on the hard drive (e.g.  all personal documents for school, tafe or work0?
Thanks

Comment: As always, BACKUP YOUR DATA Before installing or upgrading to another version, play it safe!

Comment: Most Windows starter PCs will not have the hardware needed to run Ultimate, it will be very slow to respond and possibly unusable, due to the low end PC's sold with Starter Editions of Windows.

Comment: As always, BACKUP YOUR DATA Before installing or upgrading to another version , but upgrading window won't delete personal data

Answer (score 1):

It will not imapct any data.  Be aware some versions do not allow the "anytime upgarde" so check the MS site to assure you can sucessfully do this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/shop/windows-anytime-upgrade) you will get complete information about the versions you can upgrade to.

One thing you must keep in mid is the following:

*You can use Windows Anytime Upgrade to upgrade from a 32‑bit edition of Windows 7 to a 32‑bit edition of Windows 7 and from a 64‑bit edition of Windows 7 to a 64‑bit edition of Windows 7, but you can’t upgrade from a 32‑bit edition of Windows 7 to a 64‑bit edition of Windows 7 or vice versa.*